# How does nodejs load .env files?

Tags: node.js, dotenv

path：

```
- index.js
- .env.production
- .env.development
```

> .env.production

```
TOKEN = 'prod'
```

> .env.development

```
TOKEN = 'dev'
```

> index.js

```js
console.log(process.env.TOKEN )
```

My desired effect:

```
$ npm run dev
> dev

$ npm run prod
> prod
```

Development environment:

windows10

vscode

Comment: Are you actually using `dotenv`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dotenv`   meets    the     needs.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run your development server on

```
npm run dev
```

Just include this code in your package.json file in the script section.

Consider this as your package.json

```
{
  "name": "sample-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run dev",
 },
  "author": "Raja Shekar",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "couchbase": "^2.6.10"
  }
}
```

After saving package.json file use,

```
npm run dev
```

and you'll see your development server running